# What is a "Semi Bold" font style used for?

Tags: fonts

Some fonts have a "Semi Bold" font style.

[image]

[image: ]2]]

What is it used for?

Comment: Are you asking if this semi bold is a valid arial semi bold font or are you asking what the purpose of semi bold is?

Comment: I love semibold. I use it when I feel like something needs to be emphasized, but it's just not quite bold-worthy hahaha. LateralTerminal gave a great answer below that should help you get a better sense of varying font weights. Really, it's just part of the sprectrum.

Comment: In this question itself, asking what the purpose of "Semi Bold" is.

Answer (score 6):

It's used when you want a typeface heavier than "Regular", "Book", or "Medium" but not as heavy as "Bold".

Comment: So for example this would be Arial Semi Bold: https://www.dropbox.com/s/apnn2v5b29o9vrs/arialsb12.fon?dl=0 It's doing what you mentioned, right? Maybe not at sizes 9, 10 and 14 (same thickness as bold), but at sizes 11 and 12 it works.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. I'm not going to download any file. SemiBold is a step between normal and bold, that's all.

Comment: I'm telling you an example of a Semi Bold font (Arial Semi Bold). Get it to check if it's a true example of Semi Bold. It's also shown in the picture in my question.

Comment: That does not even seem to be a font format that I have ever seen before.

Comment: Again, I'm not downloading anything. There's no need for me to download a file to explain what semibold means.

Comment: This is .fon format. It's a bitmap font, and it contains data for size 12. But it's named Arial so it's a part of Arial family and Windows generates its own Semi Bold.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Based on OP comment

> "It's doing what you mentioned, right? Maybe not at sizes 9, 10 and 14
>   (same thickness as bold), but at sizes 11 and 12 it works."

Are you asking if the file you provided is actually containing a legitimate arial semi bold?

I think you are using a file type that is too old.

> FON is a font file format used by Microsoft Windows. FON files are
>   part of the Windows 3.x font library, and contain information for
>   fonts. FON files are older font files, **which cannot be resized like
>   .TTF fonts, and also may appear differently when printed."**

### -

### -

I'm going to leave my original answer here which was answered literally based off your post:

> What is a “Semi Bold” font style used for?

My answer to that is:

**When bold is too much.**

There is a whole spectrum of weights for typefaces for just the right situations.

Here they are in order.

> Hairline,  Thin,  Ultra Light,  Extra Light,  Light,  Book (sometimes
>   heavier than Regular),  Regular/Roman,  Medium,  Semibold/Demibold, 
>   Bold,  Extra Bold,  Ultra Bold,  Heavy,  Black,  Ultra Black,

Maybe take a look at: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Medium-Demi-and-Semibold-fonts

Comment: For some small sizes there is nothing between Regular and Bold (the case with 9, 10 and 14 in Arial) so Semi Bold is same thickness as Bold; it only works on some sizes (11 and 12 in case of Arial).

Comment: Do you mean only in notepad? 

What programs are you using that have this issue?

I think this has to do with what I was researching when I found " which cannot be resized like .TTF fonts"

But maybe I still do not understand what your problem is?

Comment: It's an issue with maths, as there is no integer between 1, 1 and 2, 1. As for 11 and 12 sizes, there is 2, 1 between 1, 1 and 2, 2. Also, Arial Semi Bold appears only in Notepad, so I can't test it anywhere else.

Comment: Oh I see.  It seems like you understand why it is happening. So is your question just asked out of curiosity or is there something you needed the arial semi bold to be used for specifically?

Comment: I showed an example of a Semi Bold font and the sizes it works on. Also, in case of size 14, the thickness for Regular is 2, 2 and in Bold it's 3, 2, so Semi Bold doesn't work for this size either.

Comment: That is because FON file type is too old. 

You need to get a hold of a newer format. I actually do not see a Semi Bold Arial font for sale but I see medium for sale which is right in between regular and bold. https://www.linotype.com/145867/arial-family.html You will be able to use these at any size and will not have to worry about being restricted to those sizes.

Comment: Microsoft website redirected me here too. http://catalog.monotype.com/font/monotype/arial/medium

Comment: What? What I mentioned happens with any font format. It's because there is no integer between 1, 1 and 2, 2, and 2, 2 and 3, 2. Also, it's extremely difficult to make a vector font. Arial Semi Bold is somewhat a cheat because it only contains Arial Semi Bold data for size 12, but Windows creates Arial Semi Bold at all sizes. Most of the work this Arial Semi Bold does is just add it to family, so Windows itself makes Arial Semibold.

Comment: I was not aware that you were having this problem with any font format. That does not make sense though because "TrueType and OpenType fonts, a glyph is a collection of line and curve commands as well as a collection of hints." Thats essentially like a vector font. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162893(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: That's because I didn't use Semi Bold fonts before. And if Regular has thickness 1, 1 and Bold has thickness 2, 1, Semi Bold is impossible without it having same thickness as Bold. Simple maths.

Answer (score 0):

Because we are supposed to use as few different fonts as possible I would like even more variations in a font. The main tricks available in typography are size, weight and position. They are all used to drive attention, or more specifically to make the user read things in the order you want.

Lets talk about boldness, AKA Weight. Bolder thicker fonts stand out, look heavy and so attract the eye. If you have a big bold word down at the bottom of the page and everything else is regular paragraph text than the user will probably look down at the bottom and read the bold word first.

So bold attracts attention. Why have more than 1 bold? Because you still want to attract attention but the main bold is already used and its higher in the hierarchy of importance. You want Bold Bold read first, Regular Bold read second, because of Subtitling. You have titles, you have captions and you have subtitles. Subtitles still need to stand out.

So more weight options, more italic options, more thin options will allow you to emphasize text in many ways. This is **IMPORTANT**, this is *Interesting,* thin text is non obtrusive and falls to the back. Wide text is strong attracts attention but takes too much room.

When you have a page with several title sizes, captions, paragraphs, asides, quotes and comments, and then you need to place even another style of text, you will want a semi-bold.

Look how many variations there are for Helvetica New Lt Std (see the scroll bar?):

[image]